# How to draw a 3d polyhedron in java3d?

Tags: graphics, 3d, java-3d

I am trying to draw a convex hull into a java3d universe. I have the vertices and the faces. What is the easiest way to do this ? What inbuilt functions can I use??

Comment: Have you tried to use a subclass of GeometryArray?

Comment: Could you provide me some examples or link me to a few? I'm having a hard time googling...

Comment: This example uses QuadArray: https://vrupl.evl.uic.edu/LabAccidents/java3d/lesson10/indexb.html